# Get variable outside scope from a function inside an object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, class, scope, scoping

I have a function inside an object inside a Class.

The object of the class is initialized and I want to call the function, but the function need a variable defined on the constructor of the Class.

```js
class someClass {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = "bar";

    this.print = {
      variable: function() {
        console.log(this.foo);
      }
    };

  }
}

// And I call it from the global scope

var someObject = new someClass();

someObject.print.variable();
```

It will print

> undefined

I know is a different scope and maybe I can't access to it.

The objective of this is to have some order with my functions.

**I want to access to my function like someObject.print.variable();**

Comment: Not exactly the same situation, but the exact same set of answers applies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an arrow function, it will be bound to the original `this` in the object that defined it.

```js
class someClass {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = "bar";

    this.print = {
      variable: () => {
        console.log(this.foo);
      }
    };

  }
}

// And I call it from the global scope

var someObject = new someClass();

someObject.print.variable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```html
<script>
class someClass {
  constructor() {
    let that = this;
    this.foo = "bar";

    this.print = {
     variable: function() {
        console.log(that.foo);
       }    
    };

  }
}

//And I call it from the global scope

var someObject = new someClass();

someObject.print.variable();
</script>
```

Comment: Yes!, I didn't know about I can reference the object in let, Thanks!.

Comment: Sorry, It worked, but the Barmar's answer is cleaner. If I had the priviledge to give upvote I would have given you one.